# String.split to split data lines doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, .net, string, newline

I use VB.NET to create data for my game (for Android, Java code), this is how it look like:

```
5;0000000100011100010000000;2;2
5;1000001100010000000000000;0,1;0,1
```

where each line is a level. In VB.NET, I create new line by vbNewLine constant (I think its ASCII code is 13) then use `IO.File.WriteAllText` to write it to the file.

In my game in Java, I use `\n` to split the levels:

```
String[] levelData = rawData.split("\n");
```

However, when processing throught the data, the levelData always has a "new line" after the end. For example, the levelData[0] is `5;00...2;2<new line>`, which cause `Integer.parseInt` exception. Then I debug, and found this:

```
rawData.charAt(31) //It's a \r, not \n
```

So, I change the split line:

```
String[] levelData = rawData.split("\r");
```

But now, the levelData[1] will be `<newline>5...`.

What exactly do I have to do to solve this problem? **And please explain how "new line" work in Java String.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably it is from the code you show in VB that is the problem.

> I create new line by vbNewLine constant (I think its ASCII code is 13)

First verify this for certain, then look up what code 13 is! Here is a general [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

> code 13 is a carrige return and is represented in Java as \r
>
> code 10 is line feed and is represented in Java as \n

A good tip would be to read up a little about [NewLines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), It's completely fu**ed up, Windows and Linux uses different ways of representing a new line.

- **CR+LF:** Microsoft Windows, DEC TOPS-10, RT-11 and most other early non-Unix and non-IBM OSes, CP/M, MP/M, DOS (MS-DOS, PC-DOS, etc.), Atari TOS, OS/2, Symbian OS, Palm OS
- **LF:** Multics, Unix and Unix-like systems (GNU/Linux, AIX, Xenix, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, etc.), BeOS, Amiga, RISC OS, and others.
- **CR:** Commodore 8-bit machines, Acorn BBC, TRS-80, Apple II family, Mac OS up to version 9 and OS-9

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that vbNewLine constant put both "\r\n" at the end and hence one character is left while splitting. Try to split it by using both.

Comment: You're right, use `String[] levelData = rawData.split("\r\n");` works.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read your file and split for lines instead?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("levels.text"));
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
  String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
  if(nextLine.lenght() > 0) { // you could even use Java regexes to validate the format of every line
    String[] levelElements = nextLine.split(";");
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about `Scanner`, thanks for this useful information.

Answer (score 1):

vbNewLine is platform dependant. on windows newline is comprissed of two characters \n and \r and not just \n